# Wordpress related posts only show the last three posts in the category. Is there a way to randomize every related post?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

My wordpress related posts only shows the last three recent posts created in each category. I was hoping to have it show random posts in each category. So even an older post can be viewed. Not just the last three created. Here's the code below.

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
if ($categories) {
$category_ids = array();
foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;

$args=array(
'category__in' => $category_ids,
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'showposts'=>3, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$my_query = new wp_query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
        $my_query->the_post();
    ?>
<div class="relatedpost">  
    <a rel="external" href="<? the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(175,98)); ?><br />  
<center><h6><?php the_title(); ?></h6></center> 
    </a>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add *orderby rand* in your **arguments** and use it like below,

```
<?php 
   $posts = get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=5'); 
   foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: there is also a plugin for this.. http://wordpress.org/plugins/random-related-posts/screenshots/

Comment: I should have been more specific. Is it possible to randomize related posts in the category?